# How do I share an image among WPF projects?

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

I have a solution with a number of WPF projects and UserControls in those. Among these is a `Core` project which contains resources shared by all the other projects and all. One of these is an image file, which I have had to copy to all the other projects to use a relative file path for the `Source` property of various `ImageEdit` controls.

How can I set things up so that the image file only exists in the `Core` project, and I can refer to it in XAML in all the other projects?

Answer (score 1):

Reference the project from the project that you intend to consume the image, then use [pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) to access it.

Something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProduct.MyModule.MyView"
             .....
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/MyProduct.Core;component/Images/MyImage.png"/>
```

Build action for images should be "Resource".

Answer (score 0):

Add the image to your Core project, then add as linked item to your other projects (Right Click Project -> Add Existing Item -> Select the file from your Core project then instead of "Add" you need to click the triangle next to "Add" and say "Add As Link"). You can then reference it in the usual way from within your specific project...